# how to know whether a DML query executed on a particular date on Oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, dml

I have tried to search is there any system/log table which stores execution details of a DML query.

Comment: you can install ssms tools. for saving log (i tried in sql server 2008)

Comment: @Hirengardhariya: The OP is talking about Oracle, not about SQL Server

Comment: @DanielHilgarth OK.  but in question tag you can see sql also.

Comment: Does "DML query" mean a `SELECT` statement?  Or an `INSERT`/ `UPDATE`/ `DELETE`?

Comment: @JustinCave It may be any query Insert/Update/Delete.

Comment: I'm still not quite understanding.  Does "any query" mean to include `SELECT` statements?

Comment: 1. If audit is enabled you could query audit trail `SYS.AUD$` directly or via `dba_audit_*` views; 2. if audit is not enabled, but your database is in archive log mode, you can analyze archive log files using `DBMS_LOGMNR` package.

Comment: @Hirengardhariya: `SQL` is a query *language* it is ***not*** a DBMS product. The database system you are referring to is called "Microsoft SQL Server" not "*SQL*"